GeoServer Layer Not Displaying Entire GeoTIFF Image
I'm having an issue with GeoServer not displaying the entire GeoTIFF image. The image is about 5.23 GB and displays correctly in QGIS, but when I create a layer in GeoServer, only a portion of the image is shown.
Image Description:
GeoTIFF Size: 5.23 GB
Width: 21666 pixels
Height: 16213 pixels
Coordinate System: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84
Bands: 4 (Float32)
Bounding Box:
Min X: -60.0015218264031276
Min Y: -21.6463439891832756
Max X: -59.8968903911278971
Max Y: -21.5731276592465484
What I've Done:
Checked Bounding Box: Ensured that the bounding box in GeoServer matches the extent of the image as reported by QGIS.
Generated Overviews: Created image pyramids using gdaladdo.
Compressed Image: Compressed the GeoTIFF using gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW.
Adjusted JVM Memory: Increased the JVM memory settings in Tomcat to -Xms2g -Xmx4g.
Tile Caching: Enabled and configured tile caching in GeoServer.
Problem:
The image is only partially displayed in GeoServer.
When zooming in my application, the image quality degrades and transparency issues appear, unlike the GeoServer preview where the image appears normal.
Screenshots:
Correct Display in GeoServer Preview:

Incorrect Display in Application:

Complete geotiff img:

Layer with geosever:

Questions:
How can I ensure that GeoServer displays the entire GeoTIFF image?
What configurations might I be missing that could cause the transparency and quality degradation issues in my application?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have taken the following steps to try to resolve the issue:
Checked Bounding Box: Ensured that the bounding box in GeoServer matches the extent of the image as reported by QGIS.
Generated Overviews: Created image pyramids using gdaladdo to improve performance and visualization at different zoom levels.
Compressed Image: Compressed the GeoTIFF using gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW to reduce file size without losing quality.
Adjusted JVM Memory: Increased the JVM memory settings in Tomcat to -Xms2g -Xmx4g to handle the large image size.
Tile Caching: Enabled and configured tile caching in GeoServer to improve performance and ensure tiles are rendered correctly.
Expected Outcome:
I expected GeoServer to display the entire GeoTIFF image without any missing parts, and for the image quality to remain high without transparency issues when viewed in my application. Specifically, I anticipated that the full extent of the image would be visible, similar to how it appears in the GeoServer preview, and that the image would maintain its integrity and quality when zooming in my application.
Actual Outcome:
Despite these efforts, GeoServer only displays a portion of the GeoTIFF image. Additionally, in my application, the image quality degrades, and transparency issues appear when zooming in, unlike the GeoServer preview where the image appears normal and fully opaque.
Any insights into what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.

If the layer displays correctly in the GeoServer preview but not in your app then your app has the issue not GeoServer

I totally agree with that regarding the image quality, but not the size. In the GeoServer preview, only a portion of the image is displayed, whereas the image is much larger as specified in this post.

Then you need to look in the log file to see what has gone wrong. Probably the best plan is to tile the layer and add it as a mosaic

Thank you! That was very helpful and solved my problem.

By the way, do you have any suggestions on how to avoid missing pixels as shown in the GeoServer preview? Thank you very much!

then you should really post the answer for future users if it will help them or delete the question if it was a configuration error or typo

In my case, I was finally able to solve this problem by optimizing the image.The problem was that the image was too large for GeoServer to handle efficiently. To resolve this, I optimized the image by creating image pyramids. This optimization allowed GeoServer to display the entire image correctly. In order to do this I used gdal with the next command: gdaladdo -r average image.tif 2 4 8 16 32
